# Office 365 developer program for Education

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

We have already configured a developer tenant for O365 (with the Office 365 developer program), but what we really need is an Office 365 for Education tenant for developing purposes. More specifically, we are testing the Graph API, and the Education specific API's cannot be used.

```
com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: 
Error code: Request_BadRequest  
Error message: The following extension properties are not available:
..._Education_SyncSource.
```

Is it possible to create this kind of tenant in the developer program? If this scenario is not supported, how should we proceed to configure a stable developer tenant to integrate our SIS with O365 for Education?

Answer (score 3):

If you are a Microsoft Partner Network member,  you can request a code for an Education test tenant.  Fill out the following form, and someone will contact you to discuss our needs.

https://sdscrm.microsoftcrmportals.com/partnersignup/